# Compare substrings in multiple columns recursively in PostgreSQL 11.0

Tags: postgresql, substring

I have following table in PostgreSQL 11.0

```
code1                               code2                               code3                               code4
A (alimentary tract and metabolism) A01 (stomatological preparations)   A01A (stomatological preparations)  A01AA (caries prophylactic agents)
A (alimentary tract and metabolism) A01 (stomatological preparations)   A01A (stomatological preparations)  A01WB (herbal stomatological remedies containing mucilage)
A (alimentary tract and metabolism) A01 (stomatological preparations)   A01W (preparations)                 A01WB (herbal stomatological)
```

I would like to check if substring in code1 exists in col2, substring in code2 exists in col3 and substring in code3 exists in col4. iy yes, then keep the row else exclude.
**For example: Row2:**

> I would like to check if A(in code1) exists in code2 (A01: which holds
> true), A01(in code2) exists in code3 (A01A: which holds true) and
> A01A(in code3) exists in code4 (A01WB: which holds false)

The desired output is:

```
code1                               code2                               code3                               code4
A (alimentary tract and metabolism) A01 (stomatological preparations)   A01A (stomatological preparations)  A01AA (caries prophylactic agents)
A (alimentary tract and metabolism) A01 (stomatological preparations)   A01W (preparations)                 A01WB (herbal stomatological)
```

Pseudocode would be something like:

```
select * from tbl
where
 code1 ILIKE '%code2%' and 
code2 ILIKE '%code3%' and
code3 ILIKE '%code4%'
```

Any suggestions here are highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: where
code1 ilike '%'||code2||'%' and
code2 ilike '%'||code3||'%' and
code3 ilike '%'||code4||'%'

Comment: I tried it, but it gives no output

Comment: I have explained it now in OP using Row2 as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below query, it worked for me.

```sql
where substring(code1 from 1 for 1) = substring(code2 from 1 for 1) and
      substring(code2 from 1 for 3) = substring(code3 from 1 for 3) and
      substring(code3 from 1 for 4) = substring(code4 from 1 for 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example data shows a consistent format of "Code (Extra Text)". Further the Code lengths for for code1,code2,code3,code4 are always 1,3,4,5 respectively. Is this *always* the case. If so then what "worked for you" is a correct answer. However it does depend on those lengths. Another possibility is that the code begins in the 1st position and terminates with the first space. If this holds true then you can use a regular expression to extract the code portion then use length to compare the extracted values:

```
with exp(re) as 
   ( values ('^[^ ]+'))  
select code1, code2, code3, code4 
  from ( select t.*
              , substring(code1, re) c1
              , substring(code2, re) c2
              , substring(code3, re) c3
              , substring(code4, re) c4             
           from tbl t cross join exp
       ) s 
where substr(c2,1,length(c1)) = c1
  and substr(c3,1,length(c2)) = c2 
  and substr(c4,1,length(c3)) = c3;
```

It has the advantage that it does not depend on hard coded values. See [full example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5ff6e0e9c8d9b9380ccb8a3d9ddb8a7f).